# substituting /* in vimscript

Tags: vimscript, substitute

I'm trying to remove the verilog block comment start: `/*`

I'm trying to do this inside a function:

```
call setline(line('.'), substitute(getline('.'), '/*','',''))
```

Of some reason, it doesn't to anything.
I tried to use \V, I tried escaping.
It seems that no matter what I do, it never removes the comment.

The comment end syntax is removed with no problems:

```
call setline(line('.'), substitute(getline('.'), "*/", '', ''))
```

Any advice?

---

**Update**:
The function I'm trying to build is:

```
func! s:comment_line(set,vmode)
    let lnum = line('.')
    let line = getline('.')
    call setline(line('.'), substitute(getline('.'), '/\*', '', ''))
    call setline(lnum, substitute(line, "*/", '', ''))
    norm! j
endfunc
```

I'm using this mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> +  : call <SID>comment_line(0,0)<Cr>
vnoremap <silent> +  : call <SID>comment_line(0,1)<Cr>
```

When I pick a few lines with visual/visual line/visual block, I get a `*/` deleted but never a `/*`

(I removed other parts of the function for clarity)

---

**Clarification:**
The reason I avoided using `s:/\*::` is the errors.

The answer below suggests adding the `e` switch: `s:/\*::e`

Also, the suggestion to use

```
exe a:firstline.",".a:lastline."s:\*/::e"
```

(which executes the substitution on all the selected range), is redundant here because the function is called for each line separately (A function is called for every line in a selected visual/visual line). So in this case one must use either

```
exe "s:\*/::e"
```

or

```
if line('.')==a:firstline
   exe a:firstline.",".a:lastline."s:\*/::e"
endif " do only once
```

Comment: Use normal substitution, `s:/\*::`. This also works in a function

Comment: @G Are you sure `\V` doesn't work? don't add extra escape if you are using `\V`

Comment: @klaus When I'm using the following:
                execute "normal! s:/\*::"
then it doesn't do anything.
When I use:
execute "normal! s:/\*::\n"
or
execute "normal! s:/\*::\^M"
It does something completely different, it copies the above row 4 times and deletes the first character for each row(?) I've never seen such a behaviour before

Comment: @dedowsdi I see now that it works if I'm trying to run from the command with :call setline(line('.'), substitute(getline('.'), '\V/*', '', ''))     . Of some reason it doesn't work from my function. I'll update my question to be more accurate

Comment: @GEitan, you don't need to use `execute()` you just put the line `s:/\*::` there all by itself. Check the answer I provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can use normal `:h :substitute` ex-command:

  ```
  s:/\*::
  ```
- You can use setline in the following manner:

  ```
  call setline(line('.'), substitute(getline('.'), "/\\*", '', ''))
  ```
- Or you can use `:h substitute()` in the following manner:

  ```
  call setline(line('.'), substitute(getline('.'), '/\*', '', ''))
  ```

  I suggest you use the ex-command, it also works in a function.
- I used `:` as delimiter because the pattern had `/` in it. If I used `/` as delimiter, I would need to escape the `/` in the pattern like I did the `*`.
- I needed to escape the `*` twice because I used double-quotes to represent pattern string. Read `:h literal-string` for more details.

**UPDATE**

You just need this function:

```
func! s:comment_line(vmode) range abort
    if (a:vmode == 0)
        s:/\*::e
        s:\*/::e
    else
        exe a:firstline.",".a:lastline."s:/\\*::e"
        exe a:firstline.",".a:lastline."s:\*/::e"
    endif
endfunc
nnoremap <leader>tt :call <SID>comment_line(0)<CR>
xnoremap <leader>tt :call <SID>comment_line(1)<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to ask you to explain two or three things: 1. Is `exe a:firstline...lastline` the vimscript way of doing `:<,>s`?  2. how do I get arround the substitute errors that jump on all the lines that don't have the pattern?   3. what does the "abort" mean? I added it and didn't notice a difference

Comment: 1. yes ; 2. I don't understand the question, maybe you can open another question in Vi SE? 3. `abort` lets the function abort if it faces an error, see `:h :func-abort`

Comment: I'll try to explain as it is important to me: When I select 4 lines, 2 lines containing `/*` and the other two containing `*/`, the echoed output is: `2 substitutions on 2 lines
2 substitutions on 2 lines
Error detected while processing function <SNR>12_comment_line:
line   64:
E486: Pattern not found: /\*
E486: Pattern not found: /\*
E486: Pattern not found: /\*
E486: Pattern not found: /\*
Press ENTER or type command to continue`
I was using setline in the first place only because I wished to avoid these "pattern not found" errors

Comment: Using `abort` in your function should ignore the error outputs. Cause that's what it's used for.

Comment: I tried it again, the errors appear nonetheless.. By the way, I noticed that it only appears for the /\* pattern, there's no problem with the second substitution

Comment: I updated the answer, check it again. And what I changed is in `:h :s_e`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92737/discussion-between-g-eitan-and-klaus).

Comment: Using `:s` to do the substitution will have side-effects, like changing the pattern/search register, `"/`. May want to use `:keeppatterns` or use the `setline()` method to avoid this issue all together

Answer (score 1):

As @klaus stated, you need to escape `*` and make things easier by using string-literals (aka single quotes).

I am going to take a different tact and suggest an alternative. Commenting is a common task and a bit tricker then it seems. I suggest you stand on the shoulders of giants and use a [commenting plugin](https://vimawesome.com/?q=comment). I personally use [commentary.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary).

In case this is an exercise then I would suggest you take a look at [commentary.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) as a small example plugin or maybe this [gist](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/13bde011c01b7fc188c5).

Some thoughts:

- Try to use `'commentstring'` so it works across multiple filetypes
- Avoid side-effects like mutating registers
- Maybe create an operator so you can combine with other motions